# With Reflux, 2 stores or 1 store for a resource? (Bikes/CurrentBike vs Bikes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, refluxjs

I'm still trying to wrap my head around frontend state.  Is there a common best practice for setting up stores for a resource?  For example, my web api has:

```
GET /bikes
GET /bikes/:id
```

I started off with just a BikeStore and `bikes: []`.  Now I'm working on the ShowBike component and not sure if I should use the BikeStore (not exactly sure how) or make a second store for single items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The store concept in Flux is rather simple abstraction on the client how you get access to the data. Separate stores should be used for different kinds of data. In your case the resource is the same, there is not any good reason to keep separate stores for bikes. Even more: stores for single items is not an intended usage and should be avoided.

From the flux [docs](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#stores):

> Stores contain the application state and logic. Their role is somewhat similar to a model in a traditional MVC, but they manage the state of many objects — they do not represent a single record of data like ORM models do. Nor are they the same as Backbone's collections. More than simply managing a collection of ORM-style objects, stores manage the application state for a particular domain within the application.

Comment: But isn't a store has a direct correspondence with its view? I suppose at above `/bikes` and `/bikes/:id` has different view and each both holds different state, a collection of bikes and a single bike, how you represent this in a single store?

Comment: there is no one to one relationship between stores and views in Flux pattern. The view could get data from various stores. The store will notify on any data changes to all subscribed views, views will call render itself with new fresh data.

Comment: You don't have to have one to one relationship between stores. In your case I would keep only one store, and nothing is preventing you of havng a getter on the store to return you the bike you want to see. Something like 'getBikeById'. You still have to have some logic to refresh your list of bikes, but you would keep the logic in one place.